# How to place the results of an if statement into a new array which I can return later

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm fairly new to code and I've been stuck on one particular problem for quite some time. I feel I have a good grasp on what's needed for the problem, but can't figure out for the life of me how to return the results of a if statement into a new array which I can then return. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function loveTheThrees (myArray) {

var myTotal = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] % 3 === 0) {
    myTotal += myArray[i];
    /* What I'm looking to do at this stage of the problem is place the results into a new array which will be returned rather than myTotal */
}
}

return myTotal; // Placed this here just to test to see if the problem would post the results
}

loveTheThrees ([1, 3, 5, 12, 21]);
```

Comment: would you like to return an array, or a simple value?

Comment: So your returning the values that do not have a remainder when divided by three?

Comment: Create the new array before the loop: `var new_array = []`. Add to the new array inside the loop: `new_array.push(myArray[i]); /*or new_array.push(myTotal);*/` Return the new array after the loop: `return new_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loveTheThrees (myArray) {
var newarray = []

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] % 3 === 0) {
    newarray[newarray.length] = myArray[i]
}
}

return newarray;
}

loveTheThrees ([1, 3, 5, 12, 21]);
```

Does that answer your question? It takes any item with no remainder when divided by three (%3) and puts it into the array newarray, and returns it.

Comment: That helped a ton @TheGenie OfTruth. Although I know this is all part of the learning process, I'm looking forward to the day the syntax makes more sense. I understand how to think of the process and write it out in pseudocode, but can't wrap my head around the syntax.

Comment: What part of the syntax don't you understand? I'd be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for it.

```js
function loveTheThrees(myArray) {
    return myArray.filter(function (a) {
        return a % 3 === 0;
    });
}

console.log(loveTheThrees([1, 3, 5, 12, 21]));
```

Answer (score 0):

With an arrow function expression :

```
var loveTheThrees = (myArray) => myArray.filter(element => element % 3 === 0);

console.log(loveTheThrees([1, 3, 5, 12, 21]));
```